# How do I successfully implement PHP front-controller pattern in NGINX on Docker?

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a typical PHP app with an index.php file which is served when the root URL is accessed. I would like to containerize this into Docker containers - one for PHP-FPM and one for NGINX. Here is my NGINX server block:

```
server {
    listen         80;

    root            /var/www/html;

    # Point index to the front controller.
    index           index.php;

    location / {
        # URLs to attempt, handle "pretty urls".
        try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # PHP FPM configuration.
    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass                    my_app_php:9000;
        fastcgi_index                   index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        include                         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param                   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_buffers                 8 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size             32k;
    }

}
```

This is inside one NGINX container which handles HTTP requests and should serve static files directly or proxy PHP files to the my_php_app container which runs PHP-FPM.

What I would expect is the following:

- http request for "/" arrives at NGINX
- try_files directive checks for root directory - it exists
- index directive tells NGINX to serve index.php as the default file
- the php location directive tells NGINX to proxy pass this to the PHP-FPM container

This works on my development machine where the source files are all mounted to both containers from my host machine. However, when I try to separate the static and PHP files into their relevant containers for production, index.php does not exist on the NGINX container and NGINX does not attempt to proxy-pass the path to the PHP-FPM container where it does exist. NGINX simply throws a 403 error, as though it is trying to index the root directory.

All the guides that I've read online seem to suggest that for production Docker deployment, you should use nginx to proxy scripts and to directly serve static files. Is there a way to make this work, as I haven't found it yet?

Answer (score -1):

To make this setup work, you can use Docker's multi-container setup with Docker Compose. Docker Compose allows you to define multiple containers and their configurations in a single YAML file. Here's a simplified example of how you can structure your docker-compose.yml file:

version: '3'
services:
nginx:
image: nginx:latest
ports:
- "80:80"
volumes:
- ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
- ./static:/var/www/html
depends_on:
- php

php:
image: php:latest
volumes:
- ./php-src:/var/www/html

Comment: This does not solve my problem. I know how to co-ordinate multiple containers and to bind-mount a volume. What I want is for NGINX to proxy the index file to PHP but the server block does not successfully do this.